# How can I find hook points in the kernel for USB device additions and removals?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, ebpf

I am learning eBPF for
various observability and networking applications. As a practice, I am
developing a simple utility that detects additions and removals of USB devices
and performs actions accordingly. There are posts that suggests writing udev rules (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942781/detect-certain-connected-usb-device)), but for the sake of practicing eBPF, I plan to
implement this utility by instrumenting kernel functions with [kprobes](https://docs.kernel.org/trace/kprobes.html).

However, I found it not that easy to find the correct hook points. From the
[kernel documentation for writing USB device drivers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/usb/writing_usb_driver.html),
I learned that there is a `probe` function and a `disconnect` function
provided by a driver (in a [`usb_driver` struct](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e146caf303493c4f2458173d7f1598b76a9b1396/include/linux/usb.h#L1186-L1189))
for the kernel to call on additions and removals of USB devices respectively.
So I thought finding callers to `probe` and `disconnect` might help; but I did
not find such callers, either by searching `.probe(` in the repository or
using static analysis provided by an IDE.

Is there anything wrong with the methods I am using? How can I find
appropriate hook points for USB device additions & removals in the kernel? Or
is there an alternative solution using eBPF (such as instrumenting udev with a
uprobe)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " by searching `.probe(`" - As you could guess, the caller of that function is a generic USB layer, which doesn't know about specific driver's implementations and only aware about **pointers** to the `struct usb_driver`. Having a pointer, its method could be called using **arrow notation** (`->`), so you are better to search `->probe(`. It is called from [usb_probe_device](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19.4/source/drivers/usb/core/driver.c#L293).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your comment! With your help I've found the correct hook points; would you please posting it as an answer so that future visitors can find it?